# DrRacket Scheme Parameters

Tags: scheme, racket

Write a function that takes a list of parameters and returns true if there are no repeating numbers and false if it doesn't.

I am struggling on this homework problem.

Comment: Which part of the question are you struggling with? Can you please provide any work you've done?

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Do they mean consecutive repeats, or duplicates anywhere? E.g. should it be true or false for `(1 0 1)`?

Comment: The struggle is real. I had the same problem when I was at univerity

Answer (score 2):

Make a helper `count` such that `(count x xs)` counts the number of times `x` occurs in the list `xs`.

Then use it your function: If any element of the list has a count greater than 1 there is a duplicate.